# Preventing page scrollbar on opening a popup

Tags: javascript, html, modalpopup

So, I know that this kind of questions have been asked many times before but I couldn't find an appropriate answer to my question. I have a website page which has a good amount of scrollable data including images. Now I want a functionality that when I click on an image the image gets opened in a modal popup and the page scrolling gets disabled. Something like facebook, but the image if larger than the screen size, might be scrollable. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Whats your problem, is it scrollbar or no scrollbar?  Your title and content confusing.

Comment: I have a good length of data on my page, but on opening the modal popup the scrollbar should be disabled for the whole page. And since the modal popup's height is greater than the viewports height so only that much part should be scrollable.(so that the user can view the whole popup window by scrolling. I hope you get it this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the image is larger than the screen, you can check the screen size and compare the image. If the image is larger, set the image width to the screen width. The height will automatically change to keep proportion.

If the height is bigger than the screen height, do the same, just with the height.

And for the disabling of the scrollbar, there is a long roundabout method using javascript.

Otherwise you can just hide scrollbar, and add a div, which is the full screen size behind the image.

**The roundabout javascript way of doing it:**

Once you click on an image, you can set the body width and height to the width and height of the screen and setting overflow:hidden on the body, and when you close the image, revert the style to the original. If the body did not have a height, set it to auto.

**Hope this helps**

Comment: Thanks phillip-juan, though I got the roundabout way of disabling the scrollbar, the images that I display in the popup window are particularly large(larger than the screen-size) and I want it that ways. I dont want them to fit on the screen. Anyway of doing that...Thanks!!

Comment: if your doing it that way, you can always make the height the same size as the screen, which will then make the width bigger than the screen width, this method you will be able to scroll left and right on the image. If so, you can place the image in a div, and just position the div with fixed position. The overflow setting on the div itself will allow for scroll. You can even add click and drag, depending on what you want...